# How can I mock super in ruby using rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec2

I am extending an existing library by creating a child class which extends to the library class.

In the child class, I was able to test most of functionality in `initialize` method, but was not able to mock `super` call. The child class looks like something like below.

```
class Child < SomeLibrary
    def initialize(arg)
        validate_arg(arg)
        do_something
        super(arg)
    end

    def validate_arg(arg)
        # do the validation
    end

    def do_something
        @setup = true
    end
end
```

How can I write rspec test (with mocha) such that I can mock `super` call? Note that I am testing functionality of `initialize` method in the `Child` class. Do I have to create separate code path which does not call `super` when it is provided with extra argument?

Answer (score 24):

You can't mock `super`, and you shouldn't.  When you mock something, you are verifying that a particular message is received, and `super` is not a message -- it's a keyword.

Instead, figure out what behavior of this class will change if the `super` call is missing, and write an example that exercises and verifies that behavior.

Comment: Does that mean I cannot write rspec test for initialize? Is it a bad practice to write unit test for initialize method? By the way, I am extending database connector library. If I do not write unit test, but write integration test, I just think it is weird if rspec test requires a connection to real database.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me why we can't mock super.  It seems useful to do so to properly test initialization behaviour in isolation, and surely super is a message sent to an instance of a class, no?

Comment: No, `super` is _not_ a message sent to an instance of a class.  I'm aware of no ruby metaprogramming constructs that would make this possible, and even if it were, I'm still not convinced it's a good idea.

Comment: @MyronMarston there are some cases where you need a Stub, for example in a mixin...

Answer (score 3):

As @myron suggested you probably want to test the behavior happening in `super`.

But if you really want to do this, you could do:

```
expect_any_instance_of(A).to receive(:instance_method).and_call_original
```

Assuming

```
class B < A
  def instance_method
    super
  end
end

class A
  def instance_method
    #
  end
end
```

Disclaimer `expect_any_instance_of` are a mark of weak test ([see](http://archive.today/x8d6J)):

> This feature is sometimes useful when working with legacy code, though
> in general we discourage its use for a number of reasons:
>
> The rspec-mocks API is designed for individual object instances, but
> this feature operates on entire classes of objects. As a result there
> are some semantically confusing edge cases. For example, in
> expect_any_instance_of(Widget).to receive(:name).twice it isn't clear
> whether a specific instance is expected to receive name twice, or if
> two receives total are expected. (It's the former.)

> Using this feature is often a design smell. It may be that your test is trying to do too much or that the object under test is too
> complex.

> It is the most complicated feature of rspec-mocks, and has historically received the most bug reports. (None of the core team
> actively use it, which doesn't help.)

Answer (score 2):

A good way to test this is to set an expectation of some action taken by the superclass - example :

```
class Some::Thing < Some
 def instance_method
    super
 end
end
```

and the super class:

```
class Some
  def instance_method
     another_method
  end

  def self.another_method # not private!
     'does a thing'
  end
end
```

now test :

```
 describe '#instance_method' do 
    it 'appropriately triggers the super class method' do
      sawm = Some::Thing.new
      expect(sawm).to receive(:another_method)
      sawm.instance_method
    end
 end
```

**All This Determines Is That Super Was Called On the Superclass**

This pattern's usefulness is dependent on how you structure your tests/what expectations you have of the child/derivative class' mutation by way of the `super` method being applied.

Also - pay close attention to `class` and `instance` methods, you will need to adjust `allows` and `expects` accordingly

YMMV

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to this party, but what you can also do is forego using the `super` keyword and instead do

```
class Parent
  def m(*args)
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  alias super_m m

  def m(*args)
    super_m(*args)
  end
end
```

That way your super method is accessible like any other method and can e.g. be stubbed like any other method. The main downside is that you have to explicitly pass arguments to the call to the super method.