# Testing mixin in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to write a rspec test for a mixin class. I have the following.

```
 module one
  module two

    def method
      method_details = super
      if method_details.a && method_details.b
         something
      elsif method_details.b
        another thing
      else
        last thing
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Now I have mocked the "method" object that will be passed to the class.
But I'm struggling to access the super method.
I did,

```
let(:dummy_class) { Class.new { include one::two } }
```

How to pass the mocked `method` object to this dummy class?

How do I go about testing this? New to ruby, can someone show me a direction with this.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

I tried,

```
let(:dummy_class) {
    Class.new { |d|
      include one::two
      d.method = method_details
    }
  }

let (:method_details){
'different attributes'
}
```

still doesn't work. I get `undefined local variable or method method_details for #<Class:0x007fc9a49cee18>`

Answer (score 0):

I personally test mixing with the class. Because the mixing (module) itself has no meaning unless its attached to a class/object.

Ex:

```
module SayName
  def say_name
     p 'say name'
  end
end


class User
  include SayName
end
```

So I believe you should test your module with attached to the relevant class / object.

How ever [this is a different perspective on testing mixings](http://chriskottom.com/blog/2015/03/testing-ruby-mixins-in-isolation/)

HTH

Comment: Yes I have tested the classes that uses the mixing. I'm fine with that. I want to know how to test the mixin by itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in your specs, you'll need to explicitly provide a super class definition for when `super` is called in `#method` as ["you can't mock `super` and you shouldn't"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15857623/567863).

I've attempted to spec out all three of your scenarios with the following minor changes:

- Changed your example code slightly to become valid Ruby
- Changed `#method` to `#the_method` so it doesn't conflict with [`Object#method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-method)
- Used [`OpenStruct`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) to represent the object that `super` returns, because all I know is that it's an object that has methods `#a` and `#b`.  You can change that out as appropriate for your real specs

Copy and paste the class and specs below into a file and give them a try:

```
module One
  module Two
    def the_method
      method_details = super
      if method_details.a && method_details.b
        'something'
      elsif method_details.b
        'another thing'
      else
        'last thing'
      end
    end
  end
end

RSpec.describe One::Two do
  require 'ostruct'

  let(:one_twoable) { Class.new(super_class) { include One::Two }.new }

  describe '#the_method' do
    let(:the_method) { one_twoable.the_method }

    context 'when method_details#a && method_details#b' do
      let(:super_class) do
        Class.new do
          def the_method
            OpenStruct.new(a: true, b: true)
          end
        end
      end

      it 'is "something"' do
        expect(the_method).to eq('something')
      end
    end

    context 'when just method#b' do
      let(:super_class) do
        Class.new do
          def the_method
            OpenStruct.new(a: false, b: true)
          end
        end
      end

      it 'is "another thing"' do
        expect(the_method).to eq('another thing')
      end
    end

    context 'when neither of the above' do
      let(:super_class) do
        Class.new do
          def the_method
            OpenStruct.new(a: false, b: false)
          end
        end
      end

      it 'is "last thing"' do
        expect(the_method).to eq('last thing')
      end
    end
  end
end
```