# Rspec: expect "super" to get called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec3

I have a very short function to test:

```
def my_fn
  if some_condition
    super(@my_attr)
  end
end
```

And I want my spec to do verify that `super` gets called, but I can't do the following because `:super` appears not to be a message that ever gets sent:

```
    expect(subject).to receive(:super)
```

Comment: Super is not a message - its a keyword.

Comment: @max : it makes sense why it doesn't work, then. Do you have any idea how I can achieve my intent?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15856334/how-can-i-mock-super-in-ruby-using-rspec

Comment: But I would pay attention to the answer by Myron Marston - he is (was?) a core developer for RSpec.

Comment: As a general - don't mock object under test. Mock only objects that it's using, but mocking the same object as you're testing is asking for trouble.

Comment: You shouldn't test implementation, you should test behaviour. When you have a call to super, the test should pass even if you replace "super" with the code from your original method. So, test that the call does "what" it should and not "how" it does that.